# Android studio: dont work JsonArrayRequest

Tags: java, json

help me please ( I dont understand what the problem is. It gives an error and the text "ERROR", I can not find anything in the logs. I am a beginner and am currently studying on android development.

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, API + 0, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            TextView textWord = findViewById(R.id.textWord);
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String word = jsonObject.getString("word");
                    textWord.setText(word);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            TextView textWord = findViewById(R.id.textWord);
            textWord.setText("ERROR");
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

```
      {"Words":[{"word":"test"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was only necessary to transfer part of the code

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    final TextView textWord = findViewById(R.id.textWord);
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, API + 0, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String word = jsonObject.getString("word");
                textWord.setText(word);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        textWord.setText("ERROR");
    }
});
requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: final TextView textWord = findViewById(R.id.textWord);